# Use of `all()` function while generating prime numbers with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate all the prime numbers up to a certain limit and found the below answer for my question in another entry. Can someone please explain the use of `all()` function here. I know that it generates `True` in a case like `all([1,2,3])` and `False` in `all([1,2,False])`.

```
[x for x in range(2, 20) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of the code by deciding a single number whether its a prime or not:

**Lets see if 5 is a prime number or not**

```
calculation = [5%2!=0?, 5%3!=0?, 5%4!=0?] 
Calculation = [True, True, True]
all(calculation) -> True (because all element of an iterable object(list) is true)
```

So `5` is prime number

**Now lets see if 4 is a prime or not:**

```
calculation = [4%2!=0?, 4%3!=0?] 
Calculation = [False, True]
all(calculation) -> False (because if any element in an iterable collection is false means all() will return false.)
```

So `4` is not prime
Note: Above are not the valid code. Just Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x for x in range(2, 20) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
```

First let's evaluate what `all()` is surrounding:

```py
x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x)
```

`x % y` gets the remainder
`!= 0` does not equal 0
`for y in range(2, x)` for y in range of 2 through x

So `all()` checks all of those conditions for `True` and if so evaluates to `True`. It is what is checking for Prime as those are the prime conditions, that all numbers when dividing your current number by the others does not have a remainder of 0, meaning it would be divisible and therefore not prime.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to translate the list comprehension to English:

For each number between 2 and the 20th integer (which is 19) keep the number in the list if there is a remainder when for the division by all numbers between 2 and the nth integer where n=x (ie one less than x).

Specific example:

```
# If x is 4:
all(4 % 2 != 0, 4 % 3 != 0) -> all(False, True) -> False # 4 is not prime
```